# Setting up node.js server

Tags: node.js

I've managed to set up a node.js server, and access it on my local computer (via localhost). However, I can't access it from any other computers on the LAN.

The server is 192.168.1.103, and the client is 192.168.105

I'm using Apache for the web server, and node.js for a chat server on port 8080.

It seems like every time I restart the server, I get a different error. Sometimes I can access 192.168.1.103:8080/socket.ion/socket.io.js from the remote computer, sometimes it crashes the server with an eror, either:

```
/home/tnewhook/node_modules/socket.io/lib/manager.js:0
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { /*!
^
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

OR

```
/home/tnewhook/node_modules/socket.io/lib/manager.js:916
match = req.url.substr(0, resource.length);
```

the strangest error I've seen so far is a

```
missing resource (GET http://192.168.1.105:8080/socket.io.  error in socket.io.js:1632
```

Why would socket.io be trying to call itself?

Comment: `the client is 192.168.105` What does it mean? check this [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken in the client side socket io js there is an hardcoded ip, which explain why this is not working between 2 computers.

To fix this either upload you app on a service provider like [dotcloud.com](http://dotcloud.com) for example or nodejitsu (limited beta access only) the only one supporting websockets.

Or you can for example on both machin edic `/etc/hosts`
and add on the serveur

```
myApp.local 127.0.0.1
```

and on the client

```
myApp.local 192.168.1.103
```

For example for a procedent project I was using either a local DNS or dotcloud's to share to the world.

```
var url = 'http://myapp:8080';
url = 'http://myapp-me.dotcloud.com';
var socket = io.connect(url);
```

Comment: What's the difference between my server and theirs. Wouldn't the wrong ip still be hardcoded on the client?

Comment: You need to have a unique DNS to point to all you clients. To do that you can just put the server up on the web and put you public DNS on the client connection string or you use /etc/host to fake having a DNS on all the clients.

Comment: so...I need DNS - using an IP doesn't work? why not? I'm just trying to wrap my head around this...

Comment: You need all your clients to connect to the server right ? The client JS has to have the IP or DNS of the server. You could just put the IP of the server it would works too. It is just nicer with a dns.

Comment: I've included the ip of the server in the client files - via 

var socket = io.connect('http://<?php print $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] ?>:8080');

Comment: REMOTE_ADDR give you the ip of the client, you client is going to try to connect to it self rather than the server, this not going to work.

Comment: sorry...I double-checked my file, and I'm using $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']